# add the background color to option using jequery

Tags: javascript

I have a `select` box which `option` values are unique like this:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I need to add a background color to that `option` which value is same as  the `id`.

I've tried like this

```
var id = $('#addTaskID').html();
var options = $('#test option');
$.map(options, function (option) {
    if (option.value == id) {
        option.css('background-color','red')
    }
});
```

But I am unable to add the background color.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you mapping ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap option in a jQuery wrapper.

```
$(option).css('background-color', red);
```

Comment: Good stuff.  Would you mind marking this as correct?  Thanks and glad it helped.